# TaskStackBuilder doesn't work on my smartphone

Tags: java, android

When the notification appears and user clicks it, DetailsActivity should start, then if user clicks the back button it should go the MainActivity, my problem is that it works absolutely fine on Android Virtual Device ( API 28 ),but it doesn't work on my phone(Huawei Honor 8 LITE Android 8.0.0 API 26)  when user clicks the notification and DetailsAcitivty is being launched and if user clicks the back button application behavior is like pressing the home button and application closes. On AVD when I click back button it launchs MainAcitivty as it should be.

```
public void sendNotification(View v){

    public static final String EXTRA_ITEM_ID = "letter_id";

    long itemId = 12345678910L;

    int notificationId = ((Long)itemId).intValue();

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_ID, itemId);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(DetailsActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,App.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_1)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentText("Notification text")
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    Notification notification = builder.build();


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);

}
```

Manifest

```
       <activity
             android:name=".DetailsActivity"
             android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        />
```

I don't know what problem is, it works on AVD